# Timestamp functions not returning time

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using Postgresql 9.6 and pgAdmin 4. Fresh install on both Windows and Mac, happens on both.

I need to store the current time and date.

None of my timestamp functions are returning times.

Time and Date work fine

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE
```

Output: `2016-07-15`

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIME
```

Output: `14:27:22.333352+01:00`

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Output: `2016-07-15T00:00:00Z`

Expected: `2016-07-15T14:27:22+01:00`

```
SELECT now()
```

Output: `2016-07-15T00:00:00Z`

Expected: `2016-07-15T14:27:22+01:00`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Does in work with `psql` or any other client?

Comment: That is a pgAdmin 4 bug.

Comment: You guys are right. I tested on windows and it works with psql.
Is there a way around this or is it just an accepted limitation?

Comment: Seems it is just a display error. The correct values are shown in psql

Answer (score 0):

```
set timezone TO 'GMT';

SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

OR

You can set timezone param into pgsql/data/postgresql.conf file:

```
timezone = 'US/Central'
```

and then restart postgresql sever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bug in pgAdmin 4.

Timestamps are displayed incorrectly with the time set to 00:00:00Z
The data is stored correctly and the correct time can be observed using a different a different client such as psql

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with newer version of pgAdmin4.